# Check the CLI option given and predict corrections in shell script

Tags: arrays, shell, prediction

I have a shell script which takes command-line options. If I misspelled the command how can I auto predict the possible options.?

Valid commands are `checkout`, `checkin`, `delete`, `destroy`, `create`, `run`, `status` and etc.

```
./test.sh chk

Invalid input
Did you mean checkout or checkin ?

./test.sh ts

Invalid input
Did you mean destroy or status ?

./test.sh ec

Invalid input
Did you mean checkout or checkin or create?
```

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This might not do exactly what you are looking for, but bash-completions could probably handle most of what you are looking for?